# CrystalImageHandler.aspx - HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: vb.net, webforms, crystal-reports

Soy nuevo en CrystalReports, quisiera saber que es ese archivo "CrystalImageHandler.aspx", cuando ejecuto me sale error en donde el sistema me esta preguntando por ese archivo. También quisiera saber en donde se encuentra para poder redireccionarlo. Finalmente, tengo todos los archivos .dll menos este "CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler" ya que no lo he llegado a encontrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta solo era borrar una sentencia que se estaba repitiendo.

```
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
```

No me había percatado de esto. Saludos.